# google docs date function

Tags: function, date, google-docs

I have dates in column A that are mm/dd/yyyy. I need to now convert the date from column A into yyyy;mm;dd for the DATE function. Below is what I have to get the data I want. Currently it is hard coded. I need the 2011;12;30 to be sucked in from A2 which is 12/30/2011. Then I need to add one more day to it for the second date (2011;12;31). Any ideas?

```
=COUNT(FILTER( 'Sheet 1'!O:O ; 'Sheet 1'!O:O >=DATE( 2011;12;30) ; 'Sheet 1'!O:O <=DATE( 2011;12;31) ; SEARCH( "b" ; 'Sheet 1'!I:I ) ) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what is in Date format, and what is in String format in your spreadsheet.

The simplest way to convert formats is to use YEAR, MONTH, DAY and other [date functions](https://support.google.com/docs/bin/static.py?hl=en&topic=25273&page=table.cs&tab=1240285).

For example to convert from the default (in US locale) format of mm/dd/yyyy to yyyy;mm;dd you can use the function:

```
=Concatenate(YEAR(A2),";",MONTH(A2),";",DAY(A2))
```

and copy this function to the fill down column A.